# loop over unquoted expressions given to a function in R

Tags: r, loops, abstract-syntax-tree, variadic-functions

Let's say I want a function that prints all the expressions it is given:

```
> foo(abc(def),gh[i],j)
abc(def)
gh[i]
j
```

I want to know whether there's a good way to do this. I have worked out how to do it using recursion:

```
foo <- function(x, ...) {
    if (!is.missing(x)) {
        print(substitute(x))
        foo(...)
    }
}
```

But I feel like there must be a better way, using a loop or possibly some way of using list() and lapply() or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, there are a couple of different ways to achieve this. The way I think I'm going to use is this:

```
foo <- function(...) {
    for (expr in as.list(sys.call()[-1])) {
        print(expr)
    }
}
```

An alternative way to do the same thing:

```
as.list(substitute({...})[-1])
```

Another alternative, with no need for `[-1]`:

```
eval(substitute(expression(...)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the special `...()` syntax

```
foo <- function(...) {
  exprs <- substitute(...())
  print(exprs)
}
foo(abc(def), gh[i], j)
```

Here `exprs` will be a list you can iterate over however you like.

Comment: Thanks for that. That doesn't seem to be documented anywhere, for some reason.

Comment: I've spoken to the R devs, and they said the special syntax is considered an implementation detail and shouldn't be used. They did give a few pointers though.